# UITableView's "attempt to delete section" assertion failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to update `UITableView` with the following code:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsToInsert = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsToReload = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

/* ... */

[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
if ([sectionsToReload count]) {
    DBGLogObject(sectionsToReload);
    [[self tableView] reloadSections:sectionsToReload withRowAnimation:animation];
}
if ([sectionsToDelete count]) {
    DBGLogObject(sectionsToDelete);
    [[self tableView] deleteSections:sectionsToDelete withRowAnimation:animation];
}
if ([sectionsToInsert count]) {
    DBGLogObject(sectionsToInsert);
    [[self tableView] insertSections:sectionsToInsert withRowAnimation:animation];
}
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

Log:

```
sectionsToReload = <NSMutableIndexSet: 0x71b19f0>[number of indexes: 2 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (1-2)]
sectionsToInsert = <NSMutableIndexSet: 0x71ac570>[number of indexes: 3 (in 2 ranges), indexes: (0 3-4)]
```

(Note there's no `sectionsToDelete` in the log.)

The thing is that even though there's no deletion I get an error:

```
2012-10-04 19:21:16.769 Syntax[903:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:826
2012-10-04 19:24:51.655 Syntax[903:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete section 2, but there are only 2 sections before the update'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does a log of sectionsToDelete show?

Comment: Nothing. It's not even there - if ([sectionsToDelete count]) evaluates as false.

Comment: I can't replicate your error. When I add your code, I don't get any errors, but the problem could be in how you update your data source. You should post the whole method where you're doing this, including the data source update. I don't know how you can be getting a delete error with no deleting going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did "Clean Build Folder" and now it works like expected. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, now I have duplicated your error -- if your data only has 2 sections before this update (which is what's implied by the error message), then you can't reload sections 1 and 2. Did you mean to update 0 and 1? I'm guessing that when the reload happens, it must first delete the old data and add the new, so that's where the delete error message is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your datasource, if you delete row or section you should change the number of rows or section in tableView